# How can I combine RDS files with a different value class?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a directory with multiple RDS files (100) that I would like to combine them as a single file. There is a script for this and when I run the script I got an error in `dplyr::bind_rows() because of different class of values.
Below, I will add the script that I run and a screenshot of the error that I got. Can someone help me to fix the error?

Thank you!

`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(mikropml)
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

rds_files <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
root <- str_replace(rds_files, "_\\d*\\.Rds", "") %>% unique

iterative_run_ml_results <- map(rds_files, readRDS)

iterative_run_ml_results %>%
  map(pluck, "trained_model") %>%
  combine_hp_performance() %>%
  pluck("dat") %>%
  write_tsv(glue("{root}_hp.tsv"))

iterative_run_ml_results %>%
  map_dfr(pluck, "performance") %>%
  write_tsv(glue("{root}_performance.tsv"))
```

`
[image: error]

Comment: function `bind_rows` does not appear in the provided code. What is the single combined file? Is it about model summary statistics and not just the model themselves?

Comment: @danlooo  it is about outcomes of the model. Each RDS file is actually a list that consists of 4 different output of the model. Those are "trained_model", "test_data", "performance", "feature_importance". I want to reach the performance data.

Comment: This question can not be answered without example data and code containing the line that produced the error.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg